# Jquery UI Autocomplete "terms"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery Ui autocomplete library, and everything works great but I am having one problem with the "terms=" that is put on the end of the url.

What I need is the source to looks at "www.mysite.com/searchTerms=[searchvar]" where right now it automatically puts "terms=[searchvar]" at the end of any url i put in.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: 'http://www.mysite.com/search/autoComplete.mi?searchTerm=',
        });
```

with this, if I type 'horse', then it looks for the url "http://www.mysite.com/search/autoComplete.mi?searchTerm=&term=horse' when i need it to look for "http://www.mysite.com/search/autoComplete.mi?searchTerm=horse"

the html

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

I looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an attribute in the tags object:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
        source : 'http://www.mysite.com/search/autoComplete.mi?searchTerm='+
        $(this).attr("searchvalue"),
        });
```

Comment: when i do that I get http://www.mysite.com/search/autoComplete.mi?searchTerm=undefined&term=horse

Comment: you also need to put something on the searchvalue attr. What kind of element  $("#tags") is?

Comment: it is an input box. I tried $('#tags').val(), but got nothing

Comment: input box = input type text ?

Comment: if you share the html it would be easier

Comment: after the input is filled, if you ask for it's val attr, it will return it's content. So: $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source : 'http://www.mysite.com/search/autoComplete.mi?searchTerm='+
        $(this).val(),
        }); and then you get the postback

Comment: ok, got it working. I was just trying it with jsut the autocomplete function putting $(this).val()  &   $('#tags').val() at the end of the source. Didn't realize I needed to put the #tags input within a keypress() function.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're welcome I'm glad it worked for you! It's better when you realize by yourself right?